# How to get unique values from two 2D arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

I am trying to get unique values from two arrays which looks like that:

```
array[{A,B,C},{C,D,E},{1,3,2},....]
```

both looks the same.

I tried to add them using `concat` and the get unique values from looping.

So I ended up with this:

```
    function uniqueValues() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("arr1");
       const array1 = srcSheet.getRange(1, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow(), srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
       var srcSheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("arr2");
        const array2 = srcSheet1.getRange(1, 1, srcSheet1.getLastRow(), srcSheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
 
var dodaj = array1.concat(array2);
  
  
for (var i=0; i<dodaj.length; i++) {
    var listI = dodaj[i];
    loopJ: for (var j=0; j<dodaj.length; j++) {
        var listJ = dodaj[j];
        if (listI === listJ) continue; 
        for (var k=listJ.length; k>=0; k--) {
            if (listJ[k] !== listI[k]) continue loopJ;
        }
        
        dodaj.splice(j, 1);
    }
}
  
  var result = ss.getSheetByName("test").getRange(2, 5, dodaj.length, 3).setValues(dodaj);
  //Logger.log(dodaj);
}
```

It was working well when array looked like this `array[{A,B},{C,D}]` but with three elements it started to return duplicates as well... I have no idea what can be wrong.

Comment: I think that to provide the sample input and output values you expect will help users understand your current issue of script and think of the solution.

Comment: At the beginning You are talking about 2 arrays of values and then You provide as an input 1 array `array[{A,B,C},{C,D,E},{1,3,2},....]` . Please update the question with valid input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to retrieve the unique rows from the values in `arr1` and `arr2`. That is to say, you want to remove duplicate inner arrays from `dodaj`.

After using [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to merge the two arrays, you could do the following:

- Use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to transform each inner array to a string, in order to compare them without iterating through them.
- Use the [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) constructor and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in order to remove the duplicate strings (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821)).
- Transform the strings back to arrays with [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

#### Code snippet:

```
var dodaj = array1.concat(array2);
dodaj = [...new Set(dodaj.map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse);
var result = ss.getSheetByName("test").getRange(2, 5, dodaj.length, dodaj[0].length).setValues(dodaj);
```

Comment: works perfect! I didn't know that it could be solved with just one line.
Thanks a lot and sorry if I was not so specific about my goal.